# Is getPageSource().contains still supported

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium and Javascript, trying to use command

```
if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Yes!"))
```

To see if **Yes!** is anywhere on the page, but it is telling me the command is not supported.  Has there been some change?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Yes!"))
```

Above code snippet seems to be in Java and not JavaScript.

My JavaScript knowledge is limited, but I think in JS, the code should look something like this:

```
if(driver.getPageSource().includes("Yes!"))
```

Comment: yeah thst seems pretty straightforward except I get an errort rying to use it

     TypeError: driver.getPageSource(...).includes is not a function